# Unity + Visual Studio: Memory window shows "Unable to evaluate the expression."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Im using Unity 2019.4.12, Visual Studio Community 2019 (16.11.5) and Windows 11. When I try to use the memory window when debugging I get "Unable to evaluate the expression.". It's a new project and everything is left to default with the exception of enabling unsafe code in Unity. I have checked the "Enable adress-level debugging" under 'Debug->Options->Debugging->General' in Visual Studio.

I have created a simple C# script with a method which is executed in the Unity event function 'Start()'.

```
unsafe void Test()
{
    int test = 2;
    int* testPointer = &test;
}
```

Is adress-level debugging not supported for C# in combination with Unity? What do I miss here?

Comment: I recently used the memory window in C# successfully. Just copy the variable name you want to inspect (`testPointer` in this case) to the memory window address field. I am using the VS Professional version, though.

Comment: @PMF I usually copy the adress (e.g. 0x187d1d2b480). In another project where I develop a C++ DLL the memory window works just fine ...